# How can I tell if a process is protected?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, process

Process like smss.exe is running with PPL:

[image]

How does process explorer retrieve this information? I'd like to do retrieve the same information in csharp or cpp.

Comment: Not in any reliable documented way you could use in any production software (IIRC it relies on the opaque EPROCESS structure). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Have a look at this GitHub [repo](https://github.com/Mattiwatti/PPLKiller) and this [article](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=146)

Comment: open process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` and call `NtQueryInformationProcess` with `ProcessProtectionInformation`. you got [`PS_PROTECTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/zwqueryinformationprocess)

Comment: @Luaan - this is not true - exist 100%reliable and documented

Comment: @RbMm `The ZwQueryInformationProcess function and the structures that it returns are internal to the operating system and subject to change from one release of Windows to another.` (the same is true for `NtQueryInformationProcess`, of course). It's not part of the public Win32 API, it's an internal function. It's just that Microsoft started documenting those as well, since application developers keep using them. You're still not supposed to use them.

Comment: @Luaan - *subject to change* this is not true. nothing is changed. only new information classes added. and this is exported stable api

Comment: @RbMm This is quoted straight from the documentation. Just read the thing. Microsoft tries to maintain backwards compatibility even when application developers do horrible things, but that doesn't mean you should be doing horrible things!

Comment: @Luaan - "documentation" changed more frequently than subject of documentation. and far from all in documentation is true. really can you give example of `ZwQueryInformationProcess` - what is changed or removed during last 20 year ?